# Shorthand for addplot function

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I'm a beginner at LaTeX. I want to create a shorthand for the addplot calls in the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis y line=center,axis x line=middle, xmin=-1, xmax=4, ymin=-3/2, ymax=3/2]
  \addplot[] {4/9*x^2 - 4/3*x};
  \addplot+[only marks] 
    coordinates {(0,0) (3/2,-1) (3,0)}
    \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(0,0)} node[pin={[pin edge={red,thick}]240:{$(0,0)$}}] {} ;
    \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(3/2,-1)} node[pin={[pin edge={red,thick}]350:{$(\frac{3}{2},-1)$}}] {} ;
    \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(3,0)} node[pin={[pin edge={red,thick}]310:{$(3,0)$}}] {} ;
;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

so I could just call something like `\mynewcommand{(0,0)}{(0,0}{red}{100}` instead of the long addplot calls, with the arguments (coordinate, pinned text, colour and angle, respectively) substituted into the long `\addplot` function.

I've tried making it with `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\mynewcommand}[4]{\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {#1} node[pin={[pin edge={#3,thick}]#4:{$#2$}}] {} ;}
```

but that doesn't compile, anyone know why? Anyone know how to create such a command?

Comment: Works fine here, but you have forgotten a semicolon at the end of the first `\addplot`.

Comment: As far as I can see it works just fine, but the sniplet you posted without `\mynewcommand` does not compile. A missing `;`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. or daleif: Writing an answer?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggested command works fine, if you got errors from the command while using it I can only guess that you somehow used it wrong. There is an error in your code snippet though, and that is a missing semicolon at the end of the second `\addplot` command, i.e.

```
\addplot+[only marks] 
    coordinates {(0,0) (3/2,-1) (3,0)}; % <- that semicolon wasn't there
```

Not that you need that one anyway, as you're also adding the marks in the same locations with the three following `addplot`s.

Here is your code with the suggested command (albeit renamed) in a working example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\addmarkandpin}[4]{\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {#1} node[pin={[pin edge={#3,thick}]#4:{$#2$}}] {};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis y line=center,axis x line=middle, xmin=-1, xmax=4, ymin=-3/2, ymax=3/2]
  \addplot[samples=100] {4/9*x^2 - 4/3*x};

  \addmarkandpin{(0,0)}{(0,0)}{red}{240}
  \addmarkandpin{(3/2,-1)}{(\frac{3}{2},-1)}{red}{350}
  \addmarkandpin{(3,0)}{(3,0)}{red}{310}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And just because. Here is a version where the marks are placed with `\node` rather than `\addplot`. As written it needs `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` or newer, as this made the `axis cs` coordinate system the default. With older compat settings you would need `(axis cs:#1)`. The output is similar to the one above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\newcommand{\addmarkandpin}[4]{\node[fill,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=2pt,circle,minimum size=5pt,pin={[pin edge={#3,thick}]#4:{$#2$}}] at (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis y line=center,axis x line=middle, xmin=-1, xmax=4, ymin=-3/2, ymax=3/2]
  \addplot[samples=100] {4/9*x^2 - 4/3*x};

  \addmarkandpin{0,0}{(0,0)}{red}{240}
  \addmarkandpin{3/2,-1}{(\frac{3}{2},-1)}{red}{350}
  \addmarkandpin{3,0}{(3,0)}{red}{310}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```